# Why is a series resistor needed in a simple thermistor experiment?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

I have come across the following simple question, however I can't see any need for a fixed resistor in series. The only possible reason that I can think of is that the resistance of the thermistor would become sufficiently low at high temperatures for damage to occur to the power source.
[image]

Comment: If you didn't have the series resistor, what would be the measured output voltage and how would it vary with temperature?

Comment: Of course (taking the internal resistance of the cell to be negligible), without a second component of different resistance the voltage reading would be constant

Comment: Incidentally, if you set your thermistor up in a bridge configuration (two pairs of series resistors, preferably all the same value, and one of them is the thermistor) then you get a very sensitive measure of changes in temperature (because you are measuring voltage _difference_ rather than absolute voltage); it also makes you less sensitive to drift in the cell voltage (if the cell drifts in your circuit, it will immediately lead you to conclude the voltage has changed; if the bridge is balanced, you will read 0 V regardless of cell voltage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not have resistor R in the circuit the voltmeter would always give the same reading - the voltage of the battery.

A thermistor changes its resistance when a temperature changes.
You are not given a resistance meter.
All you have is a battery, a resistor R and a voltmeter.
The circuit as set up is called a potential divider which means that the voltage produced by the battery is divided between the resistor and the thermistor in the same ratio as their resistance value.

When the resistance of the thermistor increase, this will result in more of the voltage of the battery being across the thermistor than the resistor, so the reading on the voltmeter will increase.
So the reading on the voltmeter gives you an indication of what is happening to the resistance of the thermistor.